# How to connect iPhone simulator to Apple Watch Simulator in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, watchkit

I have trying to run my Apple watch application which is also available in iPhone but is showing (using WCSession paired status is false). So how to connect the iphone simulator to apple watch simulator. Please help me on this

[image]

Comment: I want to share iPhone string to Apple watch using WCSession